# "have dinner" vs. "have a dinner"

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

Hi I am a teacher of English in Argentina. I teach in 5 th grade ,primary school. I share the same grade with another teacher and I would like to be sure about certain points we teach differently. For example I teach verbs Have dinner , she teaches have a dinner. Which one is correct, both are accepted?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Including an article would depend on the context. If it is a habitual everyday dinner, there is no need. If it is a special dinner, then an article may be used. Please edit your question to show the context.

Comment: 'We had a dinner after we finished work' is unacceptable unless it means 'we were booked in for a dinner'. 'We had dinner when we got back' is idiomatic. But note the usage 'We had a dinner consisting totally of different vegetables last week'.

Comment: Whilst agreeing with both Cascabel and @Edwin Ashworth, I would just add, that if one is speaking of an organised dinner, to which many people are invited, then an article would be included. "The Women's Institute hold a dinner every year to which spouses and partners are invited". Or "I was at a dinner last night at which I sat next to a Member of Parliament". There are other circumstances too, where an indefinite article would be idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct. But yes, they do mean different. I feel that 'have a dinner' refers to event and 'have dinner' refers to actual supper someone(maybe speaker) going to have. For example, "We have a dinner planned at Joe's, hurry up!" showed that speaker has 'event of dinner' and "Have dinner son, we are camping out in lawn." showed that speaker is telling to his son to finish(start and finish) supper. 
I have used these words like this, maybe wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When one says "have *a* dinner, it would be referring to a formal feast or banquet (see [definition 1b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dinner)). On the other hand, if one says "have dinner" (without an indefinite article), it would mean having the main meal of the day. (See [definition 1a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dinner).)

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with specifics.

> I will have dinner ready at 6PM

This indicates a definite event. Dinner is a specific event.

> I will have a dinner ready at 6PM

This sounds awkward and not used. The `a` in this case indicates one of a set of dinners.

> I have a dinner party planned at 6PM

When dinner is used as adjective, it's more commonly added. In this case, the object is a `party` and `dinner` modifies or *sets* the type of party.

> I have a dinner arranged at 6PM

In this case, dinner is silently modifying an implied noun, *a dinner plan* or *a dinner event* but it's implied and doesn't need to be added.

In day to day conversation, omitting *a* is far more commmon.

> **What are you doing now? Want to get a drink?**
>
> Sorry, I have dinner ready for me at home
>
> Sorry, we are going out for dinner
>
> Sorry, dinner is waiting
>
> Sure, I'm free after dinner
>
> Sorry, i have dinner with a client
>
> **Sorry, I have a dinner with a client**

In the last case, it's *a dinner* as that indicates that there is nothing special, but that it's a *dinner* meeting. It's more formal and a clear indication that you're not *dining* with someone. You could say *I have dinner with a client* but it's essentially shorthand for a dinner *meeting* or *event* with the client.

The one time where you'd always use `a` is when you're talking about a specific dinner instead of other dinners.

> We had **a** really nice **dinner**.
>
> I want to prepare **a dinner** that will really impress my wife
>
> This will be **a dinner** that you will never forget
>
> After **a big dinner**, I can't eat dessert
>
> Thanksgiving is a dinner when most people eat turkey
>
> In Europe, a dinner can last 3 hours.
>
> A dinner in Japan often contains rice

In these cases, you're either speaking in the abstract about the concept of dinner or you're speaking about a specific dinner apart from other dinners.